# Replacing characters in strings. Intersystems cache SQL

Tags: sql, string-formatting, intersystems-cache

I recently reached out to this community for assistance on how to remove a specific character from the very beginning of a string and at the end of a string. In my case, the character I needed removed was an ampersand. Here is the code I used that resolved my issue:

```
select substr((rpu.userrole), 2, length(rpu.userrole) - 2) AS UserRole
```

However, now I am left with strings like this after the very first and last ampersand have been removed:

BachelorLvlProvider&ShortTermAccess&WrkflwBachelorLvl

As you can see, there are anywhere between zero and several ampersands separating these role positions. Cache seems to have a lot of functions to concatenate strings, but am not having any luck finding functions to replace characters in a string. There is a "$replace" function but I believe it only works in ObjectScript.

Can anyone assist me in replacing all ampersands regardless of how many there are in each string with the literal ', ' ? I need to separate these with a single comma and one space. I included the tick marks as that are what I use in the code for my strings.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide test data and expected output in tabular form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REPLACE in SQL as well ([Caché/Ensemble](https://cedocs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/Doc.View.cls?KEY=RSQL_replace) and [IRIS](https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/Doc.View.cls?KEY=RSQL_replace)).

```
SELECT REPLACE('BachelorLvlProvider&ShortTermAccess&WrkflwBachelorLvl','&',',') as UserRole
```

will give

`BachelorLvlProvider,ShortTermAccess,WrkflwBachelorLvl`

Comment: Both of the SQL statements, the first one suggested and the sql replace statement both work great. However, when I use them together, my output is:

Answer (score 0):

My test below works perfectly well :

```
SELECT REPLACE(substr(('&BachelorLvlProvider&ShortTermAccess&WrkflwBachelorLvl&'), 2, length('&BachelorLvlProvider&ShortTermAccess&WrkflwBachelorLvl&') - 2),'&',',') as UserRole
```